# Why does the Quran keep saying that man was created from sperm?

Tags: quran, miracles

We know that 50% of our genes come from the ovum (in the woman). So why does the Quran give credit to the sperm and not to the ovum?

Comment: That's a misunderstanding on your side. Quran even in one verse i recall explicitly says that only the male (sperms) is sets the gender of the fetus.

Comment: Note that without the sperms (as an ejected fluid) the ovum would never be fertilized!

Comment: can you give examples

Answer (score 0):

You must know that Quran is not a science book and if you check verses of Quran which speak about the sexual liquids or creation of man in most cases the speech is about liquids or fluids. Why, maybe because the most visible or observable part of the act of fertilization are the liquids or fluids.

This apparently goes ahead with the understanding of the time, as if you checked any verse of the Quran speaking of the "fluids" in a tafsir book you may find statements of sahaba, tab'yn and others who are of course not mentioning the ovum, as it was totally unknown to them, rather than speaking about a female and male fluid.

On the other hand as stated in the comment it needs a sperm (or sperms in form of an ejected fluid) to fertilize the ovum, so -based on this logic- without sperms there's no creation of man.

Also in ([76:2](http://legacy.quran.com/76/2)) Quran refers to a "sperm drop mixture"  نطفة أمشاج which is nothing else then a fertilized egg. This mixture only could have been "discovered" in the 17th century due to invention of microscopes (see [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/175025) in Arabic language). Also Quran doesn't say humans were created from sperms rather then from ejected fluids ([86:5-7](http://legacy.quran.com/86/5-7)) and yes even the eggs or ovum is [surrounded by a fluid](https://www.britannica.com/science/ovulation) (follicle).

See also [this blog-article](http://replytorachid.blogspot.de/2013/06/259.html) in Arabic and partly English.

Comment: This sounds like in retrospective, the quran is ambiguous enough that with modern knowledge of biology, it can possibly be read to mean something like what the process really is. According to many translations, it describes what 7th century Arabs thought happens. The Arabs had chickens, so it would have been easy for them to understand "every woman has thousands of eggs like a chicken, they are just too small to see. When she menstruates, she loses an egg, and when sperm meets an egg, a child starts to grow". Given how easy to explain it is, having to read it into the quran seems dishonest.